# Package/Class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

So first things first :)

I know the title seems to be easily answered. Maybe it will be for one of you, but I am at total loss here...

**The Problem**

I have a Webapplication running in Tomcat6. This webapp is a funny mixture of new sites, that are implemented with MVC in mind and a lot of *legacy* JSP sites. The latter doesn't give a shit about OOP, Design Pattern, maintainability or reusability and are all overdue to be rewritten. That said, they still work and they still in use.

So the error I am getting is a JSP compile error:

> Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 12 in the generated java file The import de.semaino.damex.utils cannot be resolved An error occurred at line: 22 in the jsp file: /jsp/include/header.jsp EcatBundle cannot be resolved to a type

It seems the whole `de.semaino.damex.utils` package cannot be resolved. The JSP in question starts like this:

```
    1<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    2<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    3<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
    4<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.*"%>
    5<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.utils.EcatBundle"%>
    6<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.system.SystemParameters"%>
    7<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.system.HelpSystem"%>
    8
    9<%
    10  String langua2 = "0";   
    11  String speech = request.getParameter("speech");
    12  if (speech == null) { speech = "nix"; } 
    13  if ( speech.equals("de") ) { langua2="de"; }
    14  if ( speech.equals("en") ) { langua2="en"; }
    15  if ( speech.equals("nl") ) { langua2="nl"; }
    16  if (! langua2.equals("0")) {
    17      request.getSession().setAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE", new        Locale(langua2,""));
    18      PropertyResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new FileInputStream(
    19              application.getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF/classes/ApplicationResources_" + langua2 + ".properties"));
    20      EcatBundle eBundle = new EcatBundle(bundle);
    21  
    22      request.getSession().setAttribute("bundle", eBundle);
    23   }
```

The lines 12 and 24 are the equivalent to 5 and 20 in this quote. The code is not changed, its just the formatting.

My `WEB-INF/classes` folder looks like this:

```
    WEB-INF/
      classes/
        de/
          semaino/
            damex/
              utils/
                EcatBundle.class
```

That should be the desired folder structure.

**The strange thing about it**

I have pages that already have been rewritten, and they are using the exact same import without any problem. The package can be resolved and the class is instantiated with nearly the same code as above. Only this time it is in an compiled java class.

**What I have done so far**

Since the *real* java classes can work with the import just fine, I figured the class itself is not the problem.

**First** I removed the import directive and the class from the page, which looks like this:

```
    1<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    2<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    3<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
    4<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.*"%>
    5
    6<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.system.SystemParameters"%>
    7<%@ page import="de.semaino.damex.system.HelpSystem"%>
    ...
    18      PropertyResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new        FileInputStream(
    19              application.getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF/classes/ApplicationResources_" + langua2 + ".properties"));
    20      
    21  
    22      request.getSession().setAttribute("bundle", bundle); 
    ...
```

After these changes the page renders fine again, meaning the other imports are working. So something with the `utils` package?

**I moved** the class to another package (in Eclipse with Refactor -> move) and changed the import directive in the JSP. After recompiling and redeploying the whole app it worked... the page that had thrown the error now renders correct. But that is not a satisfying solution for me, so I moved it back and the error came back.

**I also** tried renaming the whole package (also in Eclipse with Refactor -> rename) and redeployed but without any effect this time.

**I tried** a couple of other things that did not help, things like reinstalling Tomcat, checking Tomcats Java Path, deployed my war file on another machine, build the war file in eclipse and Jenkins and deployed it on other machines. The results where all the same.

That behavior does not make sense to me. I have never seen that error in such a strange constellation.

**The question**
Plain and simple: Any ideas?

Or more questions that I can answer to help you helping me? ;)

Comment: Great idea: stop using scriptlets.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yep, we are not writing them anymore, but sadly we still have them...

Comment: Then start removing them :)

Comment: Is it possible you have a rogue class named 'utils' in de/samino/damex?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Indeed I have (and I am ashamed of it ;) )  And I just renamed it and redeployed the app. Its working! Very good idea. But still, I dont get it... That class must have been there for ages. It has a svn revision of  `2` where the head is in the thousands

Comment: Maybe the import in your JSP was added at a later revision. Or maybe it was recompiled recently by chance after not being recompiled for a long time, and the import-on-demand kicked in.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I dont believe that. The header JSP is included in nearly every other JSP, so should have been compiled quite often. I cannot reproduce the error with the class named UtilsRouge now, still it feels a bit odd/strange. Maybe I do not have to understand everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should by a class named "utils" in the package de.samino.damex which spoils the party.

Comment: Yes there was, as you can see in the comments above. ;) But since there was no answer until now you win the checkmark.